# Single Page .htaccess Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use htaccess rewrite to display single pages without the extensions.

http://site.com/account
to
http://site.com/account.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^account$ /account.php [L]
```

Shouldn't this work? It does nothing.

I also tried a general one, but that didn't work either:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the rewrite module enabled? Maybe try checking for URL ending with slash.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^account\/\?$ /account.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I still get 404s for /account and /account/

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use dynamic rules, instead of static rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This way any page will refer to any PHP script.

For instance:

http://site.com/account will load http://site.com/account.php

http://site.com/login will load http://site.com/login.php

If you do prefer to use static rewrite rules however, then you can use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^index index.php [L]
```

I would like to specify that if you are planning on using these rewrite rules for scripts, located inside a subfolder, like

http://site.com/myfolder/account

then it would be best to add a `RewriteBase` after you initiate `RewriteEngine`